# searching a row to copy a date into a cell and repeating on the next row multiple (1000) times

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I would like to set up a formula or VBA script (probably more likely to need a VBA script) in a sheet that will check for a date in a row and copy it into a specific cell before moving down to the next row.

> **Example:**
>
> `Search row K8 - ZZ8 for a date`
>
> `Copy the first date found into cell I8`
>
> `Search row K9 - ZZ9 for a date`
>
> `Copy the first date found into cell I9`
>
> `Repeat until row 938, inclusive.`

Is this possible without massive amounts of work and how would I go about doing it?? I must admit I have no knowledge of VBA or much using excel for that matter!!

Comment: Can you clarify? maybe an example, sounds like a  use of the MATCH function have you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findDate()
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
v = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K8:ZZ938")

'Loop over the rows
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    'Loop over the columns
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
        If IsDate(v(i, j)) Then 
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "I") = v(i, j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The procedure will loop over each rows and each column of that row to find the first date and exit the row loop if find a date.
Note the use of an array to put the values in it so that the procedure will be rather fast.

Comment: This is a great example of dumping a range of data to a variant array to achieve vastly better performance over reading cell-by-cell.